# Call to undefined method "Builder::getAfterFilters" while upgrading to Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I try to upgrade from Laravel 3 to 4 but i get this error everywhere

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAfterFilters()

Someone know where this can come ?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had this error too so I'll just post my observations here. It can always help someone !

It appears that getAfterFilters() is a method that is required for all controllers in L4.
If the error says it's not defined, you probably forgot to extend BaseController in your class.

Knowing that, the obvious fix would be to extend BaseController... but you don't nececarly have to if it's not needed.
In my case, my class had to be a valid controller because of a very stupid reason. I was using the following route syntax :

```
Route::get('sse', 'SSE@deamon');
```

SSE was not extending BaseController (didn't need to imho)
But this route syntax requires you to use a controller class that extends BaseController... so I changed it for:

```
Route::get('sse', [function() {
    SSE::deamon();
}]);
```

and it now works without the missing getAfterFilters() error !

Answer (score 4):

Okay, Here is one more thing that might happen...

the method you are running on your controller might not be defined correctly in the route... for example, this is what I did myself:

```
Route::get('vendors/getData', 'Vendors@getData');
Route::resource("vendors","VendorsController");
```

which should have been

```
Route::get('vendors/getData', 'VendorsController@getData');
Route::resource("vendors","VendorsController");
```

instead! So basically what Amaud said is perfect! my getData function was not extending base controller as I tried running the function of the model instead of the controller! You might want to check that out before pulling your hair out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In routes.php, I missed out the Controller word.

**My mistake**

Route::get('/list-users/{status?}/{page?}', 'User@listUsers');

**Should be**

Route::get('/list-users/{status?}/{page?}', 'UserController@listUsers');